# How can I append dates to a vector in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I created a vector using the vector() function:

```
actual_dates_vector <- vector()
```

I then extract the Julian date (eg: 2008201) from a text string:

```
julian_date<-substr(files[r],10,16)
```

I then convert the Julian date into YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
actual_date<-strptime(julian_date, "%Y %j")
```

This gives me a value like "2009-07-28". I then need to append this to the vector initially created. For which I do this:

```
actual_dates_vector<-c(actual_dates_vector,actual_date)
```

But this gives me:

```
$sec
[1] 0

$min
[1] 0

$hour
[1] 0

$mday
[1] 28

$mon
[1] 6

$year
[1] 109

$wday
[1] 2

$yday
[1] 208

$isdst
[1] 1
```

I don't understand what's going on. This code actually runs in a loop over multiple dates, so I want the date to be extracted from each date string, converted to YYYY-MM-DD format and appended to the vector. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: `strptime` returns a `POSIXlt` object which is actually a list like you're seeing.  If you use `as.POSIXct` instead of `strptime` you'll get the result you want.

Comment: When I use as.POSIXct, as I get the following error:

> actual_date<-as.POSIXct(julian_date, "%Y %j")
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

strptime is creating the date correctly. I believe that something's going wrong when that data is getting appended to the vector. Will it help to use a list instead of a vector?

Comment: Actually if you use `as.POSIXct` you will be using `strptime` but that results will be converted to `POSIXct`-class which will not be a list but rather a numeric vector. (And there were no dashes or spaces in your example string so need to get the formatting issues straightened out. Read `?strptime` and work with the examples.)

Comment: `as.POSIXct` has a different function signature.  you should use named arguemnts:  `as.POSIXct(julian_date, format='%Y %j')`.

Comment: Realize that appending it to your original vector will not preserve the nice-looking date string. For example, compare `Sys.time()` with `c("somestring", Sys.time())` (or `c(1, Sys.time())` for that matter). Elements in a vector are all converted to the "highest" class (integer -> numeric/date -> string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer a "loop & append" approach, you can do as follows :

```
# random data to emulate your files 
files <- c("2008281","2009128","2010040")
n_files <- length(files)

# loop & append
actual_dates_vector <- vector()
for(r in 1:n_files){
  dts <- as.POSIXct(files[r],format="%Y%j")

  # convert dts (POSIXct class objects) to character with the desired format
  dts <- format(dts,format="%Y-%m-%d")

  actual_dates_vector <- c(actual_dates_vector,dts)
}
```

Date objects actually are something else under the hood. As you have seen `POSIXlt`'s are actually lists of the date components while `POSIXct`'s are basically doubles, so they're not what you see when you print them (also the printed format depends on the local settings so you can get different results on differnt machines).
For this reason, since you stated you want a specific *representation* of the dates (namely `YYYY-MM-DD`), I suggest you to follow the described approach and store the result into a vector of characters having the desired format.

Answer (score 2):

`strptime` returns a `POSIXlt` object which is actually a list like you're seeing. If you use `as.POSIXct` instead of `strptime` you'll get the result you want.

Also, all the functions you're calling are vectorized so you don't need to do this append strategy, instead you should be able to:

```
strptime(substr(files, 10 ,16), '%Y %j')
```

Or something along those lines.

As pointed out in the comments, `as.POSIXct` calls `strptime` under the hood.

Comment: This works, but it doesn't seem to correct the issue entirely. I need to append all the dates to the vector. I use the above strategy and do:

actual_dates_vector<-strptime(substr(files[r],10,16), "%Y %j")

But the code actually operates in a loop, so r goes from 1 to 40. I need a way to append because there are multiples dates.
Note: 'files' is a list of file names from which I'm extracting the julian dates

Comment: If you don't use `r` at all and just pass the file names you want: `files[1:40]` you'll get the same effect at much higher efficiency, clarity and Rishness.